# DB credentials for Hasura on Heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, graphql, hasura

I've deployed hasura on heroku, how can I get the DB credentials of the same.

I would like to use those credentials in a django app

--Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your logged-in Heroku web console, click "Data" (or click from the DB connected to your Hasura app console:

[image]

Click "Settings" > "View credentials"

[image]